# How to loop over elements and replace at the same time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over the children of body and replace body with the child's HTML. I have this code so far.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':submit').click(function() {
         var children = $('body').children();
         var arChildren = $.makeArray(children);
         for (var i = 0; i < arChildren.length; i++) {
           var htmlText = arChildren[i].innerHTML();
           $('body').replaceWith(htmlText);
         }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Could you advise me what am I doing wrong?

clarification: When I first click on button the `<body>` will be replaced with it's first child, when I second click the body will be replaced with it's second child (but the original) ... then third ... and last, then the button can be inactive. But the button shouldn't dissapear (it's under the body too).

thank you

Comment: Erm, you want to replace the body _with_ the body?

Comment: what are you trying to do? make the children of the body children of the body? what is the point in that?

Comment: Wait...what?  So you have your body with, say, 5 elements, and you want to continually replace the contents of body 5 times?  I'm not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: I added clarification to the question.

Comment: I think my answer should be what you're looking for :)  Thanks for clarifying what you want it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Look at the last jsfiddle, it's probably what you were going for.  The other ones were my path in getting there.

http://jsfiddle.net/tDkMV/1/

That should do it for you.  Straight-up replacing the contents of body isn't going to work for you because then you'll be removing your button and the child elements etc.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        domObj = $('.replaceableChildren');
        // This line really does two things.
        // It removes the first child from the objects you're looking for,
        // and then takes that removed object and puts it as the html for the 'body'
        // (which is a div with class='content')
        $('.content').html(domObj.children(':first').remove());
        // Disables the button if there's no children left to remove.
        if(domObj.children().length <= 0){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

If you want everything to start off visible then go away, go with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDkMV/2

If you're really dead-set on replacing everything in body you can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDkMV/4/

This one might require you to 'focus' on the results window, so click in there, and then press any key on your keyboard.  There are keycode checks you could do to check if it's the 'enter' key pressed or whatever.

Um and here's me trying to shimmy in the submit button every time :p  I think this is exactly what you were looking for (replace body and keep submit button).

http://jsfiddle.net/tDkMV/5/

Comment: The end is OK. I tried it but it doesn't seem to do what I want. I added clarification to the question. The intent is that I want to try to iterate through children of body when clicking on the button.

Comment: @xralf I changed my answer to fit with your question.

Comment: The fiddle looks good but it uses class replaceableChildren instead of all children of body tag. Maybe the button is little confusing in this example, so replacement can be launched when clicking some key (e.g. n as next)

Comment: Well the problem is if you replace all contents of body, what children are you going to be pulling from?  I'm not sure how replacing 'body' is any different than replacing contents of the only visible element within body.  Is there a reason it has to be body, and can't be a div?  Visually this is doing what you want, no?

Comment: I have to go to sleep now, tommorrow I will try to play with it more. Thank you for help

Comment: I want children of body because body is root of all content but maybe I can easily adjust it. I will look at it.

Comment: @xralf ok check my last jsfiddle it's probably what you were going for :)  I tend to prefer not to manipulate stuff off of 'body' directly, but I guess you can if you really know what's gonna be on the rest of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Use the $.each function.

```
var new_html = '';
$('body').children().each(function(i, ele){
  new_html += $(this).html();
});
$('body').html(new_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you are replacing the body each iteration, so it will always end up with the HTML from the last child element. Try this:

```
script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':submit').click(function() {
         var children = $('body').children();
         var arChildren = $.makeArray(children);
         var htmlText='';
         for (var i = 0; i < arChildren.length; i++) {
           htmlText += arChildren[i].innerHTML;
         }
         $('body').replaceWith(htmlText);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I fail to understand what you are trying to acheive with the above code, to make it syntactically correct change:

```
var htmlText = arChildren[i].innerHTML();
```

to

```
var htmlText = arChildren[i].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Not really a good answer imo, first innerHTML isn't proper jQuery, and second his question seems nonsensical.

Comment: @nzifnab: innerHTML is still valid JS and I think you missed my disclaimer "Though I fail to understand what you are trying to acheive with the above code, to make it `syntactically` correct change"

Comment: Oh I did miss that...  But I think it's preferred to use the `html()` jquery method, and probably a `.each()` on children.  But i'm still super confused what he wants.

Comment: @nzifnab: Existence of jQuery doesn't make the old JS way of writing scripts any bad...

Comment: @Cybernate no, it doesn't but jquery tends to do a better job at normalizing between browsers.  `innerHTML` is fine, but his question is still....weird.

Comment: @nzifnab: Though I appreciate jQuery and its immense help with cross browser issues, to get the innerHTML (and just that property which works fine across browsers), why would one wrap the element as a jquery object and then get back the innerHTML using the html function? I don't get it... In this scenario (where only innerHTML is needed), accessing innerHTML directly is better than using jQuery wrapped methods...

Comment: Well he already had the object wrapped as a jQuery object when he called `.children()` so calling `.html()` on that wouldn't really add any overhead.

Comment: @nzifnab: The elements in array arChildren are not jQuery objects, instead they are HTML Dom elements hence html() is not defined for those objects.

Comment: Well when he called `$('body').children()` all the elements returned from `.children()` are jQuery objects, if he'd looped through them via `.each` as in Ryan's answer he would be able to use .html.  Using the $.makeArray() function was entirely unecessary.

Comment: Eh, I stand corrected.  `$('body').children()[0]` is not a jQuery wrapped object, but `$('body').children().first()` (and every iteration of `.each`) is.  More concise using the `.each` >.<

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for Ryan's answer, since he both gave you the right jquery syntax for 'looping' (not really a loop, which is part of the beauty of jquery) and intuited what you meant to do, I presume-- unless you really did just want the last child element's html.  Since you also asked what you were doing wrong, some things to notice about his terse correction might include:

The use of "this" instead of creating a placeholder variable with the confusing (and perhaps reserved?) name "children."  'this' is holding the value of each child.

The use of +=.  Rather than overwriting on each iteration, this allows you to grab each value and add it to your pile of values (what you're storing in new_html).